# In Wordpress, how do I get a child page to use it's page template?

Tags: wordpress

I have a child page with the slug /en/work/ which I want to use a page template found by slug. I've uploaded both page-work.php and page-en-work.php but when I navigate to the page none of them is used.

Comment: page-{id}.php works, but I'd rather use the slug.

Comment: ask yourself if it's worth the trouble going this route, when you could simply be using Page Templates. Make a Page Template out of the parent (page-work.php or whatever), and then each time you create a child, just set it to use the "Work" page template from the dashboard.

Comment: check this, specially last answer in the thread https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55301/is-there-a-default-template-file-for-child-pages-subpages

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following link

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
  <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

And on the custom page template ("my_child.php") include the file like so:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'my_child' ); ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Now you can include the get_template_part on other pages as well like so:

```
 <?php

    global $wp_query;

    // is Page a parent page
    if ( $post->post_parent == 0 ) {

        // on a parent page, get child pages
        $pages = get_pages( 'hierarchical=0&parent=' . $post->ID );

        // loop through child pages
        foreach ( $pages as $post ){

            setup_postdata( $post );

            // get the template name for the child page
            $template_name = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
            $template_name = ( 'default' == $template_name ) ? 'page.php' : $template_name;

            // default page template_part content-page.php
            $slug = 'page';

            // check if the slug exists for the child page
            if ( locate_template( 'content-' . basename( $template_name ) , $load, $require_once ) != '' ) {
                $slug = pathinfo( $template_name, PATHINFO_FILENAME );
            }

            // load the content template for the child page
            get_template_part( 'content', $slug );
        }
    }
    ?>
```